# Which organ receives blood from arteries and veins at the same time?

Tags: human-biology

This is a question in my exam paper.  I answered 'the heart' as it receives blood from venae cavae and the coronary arteries.  However the correct answer should be the liver.  How is that so?

Comment: The questions is not very good. The lung is another organ which receives blood from arteries and veins at the same time.

Comment: The liver gets all the venous return from the GI tract, so it may well be the largest organ getting venous blood. But the question is a bad one, as every organ needs arterial blood and a number of them deal with venous blood as well (liver, spleen, lungs and heart off the top of my head.)